# Apache POI get all rows with certain cell value

Tags: apache-poi

In my project I use apache poi to read excel spreadsheets.

From some tables it would be helpful if I only select the rows with certain cell data

does anyone know if that is possible and if so how it works?

for example only the rows whose column "columnX" have a value "somevalue"

thanks for help

Comment: There is nothing built into POI for this. You can iterate over the rows in the sheet and do your own conditional logic though.

Answer (score 0):

If your "somevalue" is a String, you can use this code:

```
    String path = "src/test.xlsx";
    String param = "somevalue";
    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path); 
            XSSFWorkbook w = new XSSFWorkbook(in)) {
        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        SharedStringsTable table = w.getSharedStringSource();
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getCount(); i++) {
            if (table.getItemAt(i).toString().contains(param)) {
                lst.add(i);
            }
        }

        XSSFSheet s = w.getSheetAt(0);
        String xml = s.getCTWorksheet().xmlText();
        for (Integer i : lst) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=<main:c r=\")[A-Z0-9]+(?=\" t=\"s\"><main:v>" + i + "</main:v>)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(xml);
            if(m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group());
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code will print out the address of any cell that contains "somevalue".

---

**Explanation:**

Assume a excel sheet as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPQUB.jpg
The string cell values are stored as a list in workbook.SharedStringSource.
So first, you need to check which cell value contains the "somevalue" that you need and get the index of that value.
In this case, the values are:
John : 0
Smith : 1
Tom : 2

The sheet itself is in xml format as below:

```
<xml-fragment mc:Ignorable="x14ac" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">
    <main:dimension ref="A1:C3" xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"/>
    <main:sheetViews xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
        <main:sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0"/>
    </main:sheetViews>
    <main:sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25" xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"/>
    <main:cols xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"/>
    <main:sheetData xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
        <main:row r="1" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <main:c r="A1" t="s">
                <main:v>0</main:v>
            </main:c>
        </main:row>
        <main:row r="2" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <main:c r="B2" t="s">
                <main:v>1</main:v>
            </main:c>
        </main:row>
        <main:row r="3" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <main:c r="C3" t="s">
                <main:v>2</main:v>
            </main:c>
        </main:row>
    </main:sheetData>
    <main:pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3" xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"/>
</xml-fragment>
```

You can see that the cell are represented as:

```
<main:c r="[CellAddress]" t="s">
    <main:v>[workbook.SharedStringSource.index]</main:v>
</main:c>
```

So if you already know the index, you can use regex to extract the cell address directly from the sheet xml.